# Subquery within LIKE condition

Tags: sql-server, subquery, in-subquery

Suppose I have the following hierarchical table:

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| ID    | ParentID |  Name |           Path          | InheritanceFlag | ToEdit |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76938 | NULL     |   1   |         (76938)         | 1               | X      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76942 | 76938    |  1.1  |     (76938)\(76942)     | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76952 | 76942    | 1.1.1 | (76938)\(76942)\(76952) | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76961 | 76942    | 1.1.2 | (76938)\(76942)\(76961) | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76943 | 76938    |  1.2  |     (76938)\(76943)     | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76944 | 76938    |  1.3  |     (76938)\(76944)     | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76946 | 76944    | 1.3.1 | (76938)\(76944)\(76946) | 1               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76947 | 76944    | 1.3.2 | (76938)\(76944)\(76947) | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76948 | 76944    | 1.3.3 | (76938)\(76944)\(76948) | 1               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76945 | 76938    | 1.4   | (76938)\(76945)         | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

My input is a table of IDs (it's a JSON string that I converted) and I want to select those IDs and their descendance (children and children's children, etc). For example, if the IDs are `76942` and `76946`, it should return me the rows the following rows:

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| ID    | ParentID |  Name |           Path          | InheritanceFlag | ToEdit |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76942 | 76938    |  1.1  |     (76938)\(76942)     | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76952 | 76942    | 1.1.1 | (76938)\(76942)\(76952) | 0               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76961 | 76942    | 1.1.2 | (76938)\(76942)\(76961) | 1               | 1      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
| 76946 | 76944    | 1.3.1 | (76938)\(76944)\(76946) | 1               | 0      |
+-------+----------+-------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

How can I manage to create this query ? I used to do it with a simple `LIKE` with the `Path`, but since it's now a list, I can't use it.

```
SELECT  
    [pkID]
FROM    
    [dbo].[t_Activites]
WHERE   
    [sFullPath] LIKE CONCAT('%(', @id, ')%')
```

For those interested in the CROSS APPLY solution, here it is. I ran the Execution Plan and it is more efficient.

```
SELECT  A.pkID
FROM    t_Activites A
CROSS APPLY @Ids
JOIN    t_Activites A1
    ON  A1.pkID = s.id
WHERE   A.sFullPath LIKE CONCAT('%(', A1.pkID, ')%')
```

Comment: What does `@id` look like?

Comment: You'll want the ids in a form you can JOIN to, and a recursive CTE. Unfortunately, the latter isn't something I do often enough to be able to put together a quick answer, but at least this will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @GMB the example using @id is a simple `INTEGER`. It was how I managed to do it for 1 ID at the time. But now, I have a list of IDs and need to treat them in a batch

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy: so, what does this of ids look like? Is it a string? A table variable?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Indeed, I was thinking of going with CTE, but I'm no experienced enough either. I'm trying `CROSS APPLY` at the moment, I will post if I find something that works a bit

Comment: @GMB A table variable. (In reality, it's a JSON I parsed into a table variable with one column, named IDs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table variable, say `@ids(id)`, you can use `exists`:

```
SELECT a.pkID
FROM dbo.t_Activites a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ids i WHERE a.sFullPath LIKE CONCAT('%(', i.id, ')%'))
```

Comment: It works, thanks, I managed to make it work with `CROSS APPLY`, but your solution is simpler so I will take it thanks